# Requiring checking checkbox during in custom Django sign-up form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Im preparing customized Django registration form. I need adding two checkboxes that are required (RODO consent and consent for using images). How to declare in Django that this checkboxes must be checked before form could be send? Form is based on model and it looks like this:

Models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'),max_length=50)
   last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'),max_length=150)
   is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   RODO_consent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   image_consent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   marketing_consent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

   objects = CustomUserManager()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.email
```

Forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):


class Meta(UserCreationForm):
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('email','password1','first_name','last_name','RODO_consent','image_consent','marketing_consent')
```

Comment: This is more likely a client side problem than something you would do in Django. How are you rendering your front end?

Comment: Front end is generated using the simplest way - just adding <form...> {{form}} <\form> to site template

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom validation in your `CustomUserCreationForm`. `field_names` would be your `RODO_consent` and `image_consent`

```
def clean_field_name(self, field_name):
    is_filled = self.cleaned_data.get(field_name)
    if not is_filled:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')
    return is_filled
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible for Django to add “required” attribute directly to checkbox HTML or I have to do form template myself?

Comment: You can add something like this to your forms:  ```RODO_consent = forms.BooleanField(required=True)```  
Let me know if this works